# "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans-7, java-6, unsupported-class-version

I know that the title is almost identical to other questions, but, I've not been able to resolve my problem with those answers.

This is the problem:

I have 2 almost identical projects (one has been cloned from the other with mercurial) and some changes have been made.
After the last pull from the original project, the following error appears when I try to run the project. I know that means that the project is being compiled with java7 and run with java6.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/[...]/Start : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

The original project keeps running normally.

It runs if I change the Java Platform in the project properties to java7, but I need the project to run on java6, so that's not an option.

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.2 (Build 201207171143)
Java: 1.6.0_35; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 20.10-b01
System: Linux version 3.2.0-32-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add more than 1 jdk to your environment and you can decide which one to use. try to add the jdk 6 and compile it based on that.